# Bootstrap Modal fade woes

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I recently updated our Bootstrap plugins file to version 2.2.1 (the concatenated version offering all plugins).

Swapped over all old data-* api references for the modals as we'd been using 1.4 - everything was hunky dorey. Something we'd never been using was the animations, offered with the 'fade' class.

So today I wanted to pop the animations on, can anyone explain why adding the `fade` class not only breaks the modal entirely (displays the backdrop, but the modal itself is never set to display) but also makes the 'trigger' event handler not work?

I have a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kerry350/ahB6C/5/) showing the problem. It's happening cross-browser, so I know the errors on my side somewhere. `fade` removed - all good, `fade` on - broken :(

The styles seem fine? The markup is as I've always used and the minified plugin source was updated as I say very recently.

Can anyone help before I spend even longer down a rabbit hole for what I hope is a silly oversight :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved now. It was my own fault, I'd overlooked the actual 'component animations' CSS that needs adding.

It took me a while to get there debugging wise, but in the end I saw that the backdrop method callback wasn't being executed from here `doAnimate ?
            this.$backdrop.one($.support.transition.end, callback) :
            callback()`.

The reason the callback was never executed is obvious now - missing CSS classes therefore no transitions were applied, therefore no transition end event to hook on to. So the backdrop element was getting it's `in` class applied, but never the actual modal as the callback was never reached, and that's also why the 'trigger' seemed to stop working - there was just a big backdrop positioned over the top but opacity set to 0.

Ah it all seems so silly now :)